# Search item in multilevel array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array like this:

```
[{Object_id: "000", label: "Avertissement"},{Object_id: "001",label: "Chapitre 1",entry: [{Object_id: "001/003",label: "Chapitre 1-1"},{Object_id: "001/004",label: "Chapitre 1-2",entry: [{Object_id: "001/004/001",label: "Chapitre 1-2-1"},{Object_id: "001/004/002",label: "Chapitre 1-2-2"}]}]}];
```

I want to find the Object Id of all the parents, providing the Object_id item
So if I give to the function the value "001/004/002", it returns ["001", "001/003"], I mean, an array of all the ids of the parents (like a bread crumb). The array of arrays can have up to five levels.

I prefer a solution based in underscore, but pure JS or jquery is OK.

Comment: do you have some code to show?

Comment: Please confirm - `["001", "001/003"]` or `["001", "001/004"]`? The latter seems to make sense.

Comment: did you try something ??? anything ???

Comment: Your array is malformed.

Comment: Please validate you data. Its not a valid JOSN.

Comment: You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json

Comment: For anyone giving it a crack, here's the valid array... `var o = [{Object_id: "000",  label: "Avertissement"},{Object_id: "001",label: "Chapitre 1",entry: [{Object_id: "001/003",label: "Chapitre 1-1"},{Object_id: "001/004",label: "Chapitre 1-2",entry: [{Object_id: "001/004/001",label: "Chapitre 1-2-1"},{Object_id: "001/004/002",label: "Chapitre 1-2-2"}]}]}];`

Comment: THank you, edited the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Nina just beat me to it! Here's my solution anyway. It also uses recursion to find exact item you ask for, but keeps track of the hierarchy it's gone through.

```
var o = [{
    Object_id: "000",
    label: "Avertissement"
}, {
    Object_id: "001",
    label: "Chapitre 1",
    entry: [{
        Object_id: "001/003",
        label: "Chapitre 1-1"
    }, {
        Object_id: "001/004",
        label: "Chapitre 1-2",
        entry: [{
            Object_id: "001/004/001",
            label: "Chapitre 1-2-1"
        }, {
            Object_id: "001/004/002",
            label: "Chapitre 1-2-2"
        }]
    }]
}];

var getParentIds = function(id, o, hierarchy) {
    var find = function(id, o) {
        for (var i = 0; i < o.length; ++i) {
            var ob = o[i];
            if (ob['Object_id'] == id) {
                return ob;
            } else {
                if (ob['entry'] != null) {
                    hierarchy.push(ob);
                    return find(id, ob['entry']);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    var theObject = find(id, o, []);

    for (var i = 0; i < hierarchy.length; ++i) {
        document.write(hierarchy[i]['Object_id'] + '<br/>');
    }
};

getParentIds('001/004/002', o, []);
```

Comment: Sure, you could add that in if you like - just in the `for` loop in the `getParentIds` function.   https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/ky0ywpnt/

Answer (score 1):

since your id's already contain the path, why not using it?

```
function parentIds(id){
    for(var out = [], i = id.indexOf("/"); i > -1; i = id.indexOf("/", i+1))
        out.push(id.substr(0, index));
    return out;
}

parentIds("001/004/001")
```

otherwise

```
function parentIds(id, data){
    var result = [];
    function traverse(node){
        if(node){
            //if(node instanceof Array) return node.some(traverse);  //ES6
            if(node instanceof Array) return _.some(node, traverse); //underscore
            if(node.Object_id === id) return true;
            if(traverse(node.entry)){
                result.push(node.Object_id);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    traverse(data);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This proposal gets all parents of the given string with a recursion call of `iter()`.

```js
var data = [{ Object_id: "000", label: "Avertissement" }, { Object_id: "001", label: "Chapitre 1", entry: [{ "Object_id": "001/003", "label": "Chapitre 1-1" }, { "Object_id": "001/004", "label": "Chapitre 1-2", entry: [{ "Object_id": "001/004/001", "label": "Chapitre 1-2-1" }, { "Object_id": "001/004/002", "label": "Chapitre 1-2-2" }] }] }],
    result = getParentId("001/004/002", data);

function getParentId(id, data) {

    function iter(id, data, level) {
        var key = id.split('/').filter(function (_, i) { return i <= level; }).join('/'),
            result = [];
        data.some(function (a) {
            if (a.Object_id === key) {
                result.push(a.Object_id);
                if (id !== key && Array.isArray(a.entry)) {
                    result = result.concat(iter(id, a.entry, level + 1));
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        return result;
    }

    return iter(id.substring(0, id.lastIndexOf('/')), data, 0);
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```